# Metamask not recognizing Hardhat network on EC2 instance: "Could not fetch chain ID Is your URL correct"

Tags: amazon-ec2, metamask, hardhat

Using the following installation on AWS EC2 Server Ubuntu 20.04

```
npm install --save-dev hardhat@2.8.4
```

and the following command :

```
npm hardhat node
```

getting the response ( 127.0.0.1:8545 which is not going to connect for a remote client to AWS localhost )
[image]
resulting in my problem with the connection via metamask:
[image]

I have tried a number of variations in the hardhat.config.js including :

```
networks: { 
    localhost: { 
        url: "http://ec2-44-242-170-11.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:8545"
    }
    hardhat: {
         chainId: 31337
    }
}
```

I have tried 1337, 2710 as chainID, examining Hardhat console to find the chainID as well as  variations of the hardhat.config.js as well as different browsers ( no problems connecting with ganache on this instance ).I can connect to my instance if I run react.js so there are no issues with security groups either.

Answer (score 0):

thanks to everyone who viewed my issue, it tured out that this was resovled by using --hostname    after the running of npx hardhat node
I am not sure why this was not prominent in the hardhat documentation